# Html Bootstrap Dynamic Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it OK to make the navigation bar on my site dynamic. E,g, the html for the `<nav>` section with the layout for the navigation bar will be stored in a database and loaded into a div when the page loads. That way changes to the bar will be distributed to all pages on the site.

Is that a good idea or will there be negative side effects for SEO or any other reason?

Comment: So basically you are trying to have the same header on each page..? Why use a database for this and not use another php-file e.q. header.php? The content (list items) or whatever is good to take from the database

Comment: Yeah good point, thanks.

Comment: Marked as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are trying to have the same header on each page..? Why use a database for this and not use another php-file e.q. header.php? The content (list items) could be taken from a database but a `header.php` is enough. using `include 'header.php';` at the top of each php file.